# Visualforce User Lookup to fetch Partner users

Tags: visualforce, user, partner-communities, apexinputfield, lookup-field

I need to Lookup a Partner User from my VF page for which I leverage the Standard Salesforce lookup and use apex:inputField and point to Account.Owner field.

Here is a trimmed version of my VF which essentially shows the problem:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!account.ownerId}"/>
</apex:form>
```

My lookup will allow me to lookup Standard Users just fine but Community Users never appear.
Basically it is missing the Standard "User Type" dropdown consisting of values like "Standard User", "Community User" etc that is available in Standard pages.

I have gone through this [very old link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095jLIAQ) and seems my problem is just the same (search results restricted to lktp=StandardUserLookup) but I am clueless what the resolution can be. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, account cannot have Partner user as owner. 
Have you tried another object? Try this with any custom object.

Comment: I have tested that in my org I can set a user with Partner role as Account Owner. Same user comes from Account standard but not from VF. But I will try as you say and change the lookup to a custom object owner lookup.

Comment: sorry for coming back late, however I tested using other custom objects too. It never fetches the users in Partner Roles. Any thoughts?